# Returning Error in a Dynamic MySql Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I am developing some functions/procedures for a much larger system, that is gona be used in others tables, so i tried to create a Dynamic MySql Procedure, to pass the name of the tables by variables,and get an "InOut" variable to return the result that i want, but it is returning me some Syntax error, i don't know where i am geting wrong in the code, so if someone knows a way better to do it, or get where the error is, i will be very thankfull!

Here is The Error that is returning:

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'If Exists (Select cliente26 From da26s9                           Where da26s9.c' at line 1.

Here is how i am Calling the Procedure:

```
Call FilTabMes('da26s9','codigo26','cliente26','002715',@string);
```

Here is The Procedure that i am struggling with:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `FilTabMes`(vTabMes_ Char(32),vCodMes_ Char(32),vCodTab_ Char(32),vComFin_ Integer,InOut vResPes_ Char(32))
Begin 
   Declare vSelTab VarChar(1000);
   Set @vSelTab = CONCAT('Select ',vCodTab_,' From ',vTabMes_,'
                          Where ',vTabMes_,'.',vCodMes_," Like ",vComFin_);
   Set @vSelTab = CONCAT('If Exists(',@vSelTab,')
                             Begin
                                Set vResPes_ = "T";
                             End
                          Else
                             Begin
                                Set vResPes_ = "F";
                             End
                          End If');
   Prepare stmt1 From @vSelTab;
   Execute stmt1;   
End
```

Comment: You cannot execute compound statement in prepared statement. Describe the task in details, not the attempt to solve it.

Comment: about this Compound statement in a prepared statement, i managed to create a dinamic procedure similar to this one, and it worked ok, it wasn't supose to work?, about the task, in the software that i work there is a feature to equipment location, i store the location in a table, and the equipments in another, however, i need to filter the equipments by client, and the client is stored in the location table, so, what i am trying to do is go through each equipment in the equipment table, see if he belongs to a location table that it's client is equal to a variable that i am passing on.

Comment: This may be solved in a query, like `WHERE equipment.location = client.location` (or `WHERE DISTANCE(equipment.location, client.location) < @max_distance`).

Comment: I tried like this and it worked, thank you! however i am strugling with another problem, i need a method to get a return from this procedure, i tried to call him from a function, get a value (if it found something or not) from an "OUT" variable and then return what i want, but, in MySql, any type of DynamicSql cannot be called from a funtion, so i'm stuck in here, do you have any idea of a solution to this problem? i searched almost all topics looking for a solution for this problem and i didn't found anything, thanks for the atention!.